# IPTables not working as expected for ssh control

Tags: ssh, iptables

I have the following rules, which for testing is all that I have:

```
  iptables -F
  iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
  iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -j DROP
  iptables -A INPUT -i em1 -p tcp --dport 22  -j ACCEPT
  iptables -A OUTPUT -o em1 -p tcp --sport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

I took the match on connection state off to simplify the rules. Yet, I am unable to connect to ssh from em1 interface. Why?

If I take the last four lines off, I am able to ssh with ease. I have two interfaces. I am on the LAN on the em1 interface. Em1 interface of the iptables system has IP address set to 192.168.1.22 and I am trying to ssh from 192.168.1.13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you execute the rules in that order, you're dropping packets on port 22 before you can accept them.

If you list the rules, it processes them in order and when hitting a rule that matches stops.  It's not like routing where it goes from the most specific to the most generic.

If you change the order you enter the rules to:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i em1 -p tcp --dport 22  -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o em1 -p tcp --sport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -j DROP
```

It should accept destination port 22 on interface em1 and not get to the rule telling it to drop the packets.

Comment: I saw policies set at the beginning in many IPTABLES scripts where the general policy (-P) was used at the start to drop first.  I guess the packet traverses the rules/chains and once accepted, is out of the chain and moves to the next chain. If dropped in the rules, it is totally out. If no rule matched it in the chain, then the policy for the chain applies. Right? Also, if I ssh to the ip address assigned to em2, it still succeeds. I am on the LAN on em1. I would have expected success to ssh on the IP address assigned to em1 only and not em2. Can you shed some light on this?

Comment: The general policy is the default (if nothing matches), so it doesn't matter when you define the general policy.  If a rule matches, then the action specified is taken, if ACCEPT or DROP it's done.  If ssh is going through em2 it should be dropped since the rule being matched would be the later rule of protocol and destination port -- I'd need more information to see what is happening there (and possibly you could use the LOG destination to troubleshoot).